# How to add the fonts for email in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

> When i am changing the fonts in Magento_Email/email/header.html
>   template the fonts are not changing. If i import the url in email
>   template also not changing the fonts.
>
> Kindly please provide a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please put below code in command line after that its working :

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below steps:-**

```
sudo rm -rf var/*
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*


sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```